# Prove that a relation R on A is antisymmetric if and only if $R∘R^{-1} \subseteq I_A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, function-and-relation-composition

If: I tried to take some element $(a,b)∈R∘R^{-1}$ and show that we have some $c∈A$ s.t. $(a,c)∈R^{-1}$ and $(c,b)∈R$, and use the fact that $R∘R^{-1} \subseteq I_A$ which gives that $a=b$.  I then tried to show that $(b,c)∈R$ with $b≠c$ and find a contradiction but couldn't get anything.

I didn't get to the only if yet because I've been very stuck.  Any help is appreciated.

Also note we have our standard definition of antisymmetry: A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is said to be antisymmetric if, for all $x∈A$ and $y∈A$, whenever $(x,y)∈R$ and $(y,x)∈R$, then $x=y$.

Comment: In MathJax you need to use dollar signs to delimit math expressions.  Would you mind editing to fix?

Comment: Yeah, still trying to figure out MathJax, sorry haha

Answer (score 3):

I think you really want to prove the correct

> The relation $R$ on $A$ is antisymmetric iff $R \cap R^{-1} \subseteq I_A$.

So not composition of relations, but intersection!

To show the original statement is false, let $R$ be $\le$ on $A=\mathbb{N}$, say (classically antisymmetric). Then $(1,2) \in R$, $(3,1) \in R^{-1}$ so $(3,2) \in R \circ R^{-1}$ but $(3,2) \notin I_A$.

The corrected statement is really a restatement of the definition of antisymmetricity of $R$, try it.

Comment: I'm just confused because the problem is coming from a textbook which specifically calls for composition, and the problem is stated verbatim as the title of this thread.  I do agree that it would make far more sense as intersection, and perhaps that explains why I've been unable to find a proof for why it's true haha.

Comment: @GeorgeWKush Books do have typos. I gave a counterexample to show it's false.

Comment: @GeorgeWKush Maybe a dot is used for intersection, that's an older notation. $R \cdot R^{-1}$ vs $R\circ R^{-1}$ confusion?